# Tcp checksum value for given packet

Tags: tcp, checksum

I have written a tcp checksum calculation function. I need to check if it works as specified in http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt (which uses ipv4 addresses to calculate the pseudoheader).

To do this I need to have a known checksum value for a given packet. Does anybody have such a known checksum/packet pair for me or tell me where I can find it? Preferably one where an odd number of data bytes is sent. For example the checksum of:

```
Sourceport: 9999
Destinationport: 11111
seqnumbr: 5555
acknumber: 6666
Dataoffset: 5
Flags: ACK and PUSH
Window: 8000
Urgentpointer: 0
Options: no options
data: {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05}

Source IP (for the psuedo header): 192.168.0.10
Destination IP (for the psuedo header): 192.168.0.20
```

How can I find out what the checksum for that tcp packet is?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use wireshark.